# Heroku R10 error in jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack Buildpack

Tags: c#, heroku, .net-core

I am quite new to Heroku, but I'm building an app that needs to stay online and receive and process events from another server. I keep getting the same log:

```
2021-07-10T22:34:14.667474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `cd /app/heroku_output && ./ForceGamesHelper`
2021-07-10T22:34:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-07-10T22:35:15.055194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-07-10T22:35:15.105411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-07-10T22:35:15.191790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-07-10T22:35:15.258254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am keeping the process alive with a `while` loop and an exit condition that can be changed asynchronously.

I have tried different solutions around Procfiles and stuff like that, but the commands I've tried don't seem to exist in my project.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to run .net core console app using web process (heroku trying to listen to $PORT can't do it and crashes).

Try to use custom Procfile and set worker process instead of web.

Heroku process model https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model
Check the existing issues here https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack/search?q=worker&type=issues